# What's the use of "flag" in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, flags

When i was training with an exercise for predictive modeling, I couldn't understand the use of flags. I googled it but I couldn't find the best explanation.

```
train = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/Analytics Vidhya/Desktop/challenge/Train.csv')
test = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/Analytics Vidhya/Desktop/challenge/Test.csv')
train['Type'] = 'Train' #Create a flag for Train and Test Data set
test['Type'] = 'Test'
fullData = pd.concat([train,test], axis=0) #Combined both Train and Test Data set
```

Can you explain what does flag means in Python [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) and what's the importance of flags. Thank you.

Comment: when you need to `concat` multiple data sets together and still be able to distinguish which data came from which data set, what other approach would you better use?

Comment: Thank you @Aprillion I get the idea!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess it's easier and faster to show it as an example:

```
In [102]: train = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 5, (5, 3)), columns=list('abc'))

In [103]: test = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 5, (3, 3)), columns=list('abc'))

In [104]: train
Out[104]:
   a  b  c
0  3  4  0
1  0  0  1
2  2  4  1
3  4  2  0
4  2  4  0

In [105]: test
Out[105]:
   a  b  c
0  1  0  3
1  3  3  0
2  4  4  3
```

let's add `Type` column to each DF:

```
In [106]: train['Type'] = 'Train'

In [107]: test['Type'] = 'Test'
```

now let's join / merge (**vertically**) both DFs - the `Type` column will help to distinguish data from two different DFs:

```
In [108]: fullData = pd.concat([train,test], axis=0)

In [109]: fullData
Out[109]:
   a  b  c   Type
0  3  4  0  Train
1  0  0  1  Train
2  2  4  1  Train
3  4  2  0  Train
4  2  4  0  Train
0  1  0  3   Test
1  3  3  0   Test
2  4  4  3   Test
```

Comment: Thank you very much @MaxU I find your example very clear.